# Geckodriver not being found

Tags: python, selenium

I am relatively new with this, and I am currently using python 2.7 with selenium. When running the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get an error saying that 'geckodriver' executable must be in PATH. I then put it in /usr/local/bin, and it still did not work. I also tried doing `browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'your\path\geckodriver')`, and it still did not work. Additionally, after using `chmod +x geckodriver` in the terminal, it would give me an error. What solution will fix this problem?

Comment: If you are using chmod then I think you are using linux, and in linux the routes are given by the separator: `/`, for example in my case: `/usr/bin/geckodriver`

Comment: you can put the gecko driver to your work space location then in such case you don't need to specify location in the code.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear about the OS on which you are triggering your scripts. While you work with Selenium 3.5.x you can download the `geckodriver` binary and place it anywhere within your system and reference it by providing the absolute path of the `geckodriver` binary while you initialize the `webdriver` instance. On my `Windows 8 Pro` system this is the working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Console Output:

```
Page Title is : Google
```

Perhaps on Linux systems, we have to do:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/absolute_path/geckodriver')
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```